# Getting error in Botium box community edition setup

Tags: chatbot

Getting error :--

[GraphQL error]: Message: Your token is invalid. It might have expired or you might be using a token from a different project., Location: undefined, Path: undefined

In botium-box community edition setup

Please guide.

Step1 :

```
curl --output docker-compose-all.yml https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codeforequity-at/botium-box-basic-dist/master/docker-compose-all.yml
```

Step2: `docker-compose -f docker-compose-all.yml up`

Getting error in step2.

Comment: Can you please post the full log output here ?

Comment: I discussed with the team, the 1.7.0 build of Botium Box Community Edition is broken - please wait some hours, there will be a 1.7.1 build in some hours.

Answer (score 0):

The Botium Box 1.7.0 build is broken. Please use the latest 1.7.1 build from Dockerhub.

Here are the steps to pull the newest images:

```
> docker-compose -f docker-compose-all.yml stop
> docker-compose -f docker-compose-all.yml pull
> docker-compose -f docker-compose-all.yml up -d
> docker-compose -f docker-compose-all.yml logs -f
```